# Make React hook step into loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I adjust the below code so that after "loop" button is pressed, and then "change data" button is pressed, I can see the loop print changed data - that is, "bar" not "foo"?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-gn5yw

```
const sleep = async(ms: number) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const Looper = () => {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState<string>('foo')

    const runOnce = () => {
        console.log(data)
    }

    const loop = async() => {
        while (true) {
            runOnce()
            await sleep(1000)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={loop}>Loop</button>
            <button onClick={runOnce}>Run once</button>
            <button onClick={() => setData('bar')}>Change data in state</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think this is a trivialized example -- what is that you're really after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `data` change doesn't result in any *visual* changes in the component, it doesn't need to be state. The `runOnce` function containing the data from the old closure is the problem (`data` is declared with `const`, after all - it can't change for a given invocation of `loop`)

Use a ref instead:

```
const dataRef = useRef('foo');
const runOnce = () => {
    console.log(dataRef.current)
}
```

```
<button onClick={() => { dataRef.current = 'bar'; }}>Change data in state</button>
```